# apply vector written function to all elements in list in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list consisting of 4 double columns

```
class MainE
{
     class cPoint
    {
        public double a;
        public double b;
        public double c;
        public double d;
    };

static void Main()
{
    List<cPoint> lst = new List<cPoint>();
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =613, b = 261, c=163,d=345 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =271, b = 251, c=363,d=444 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =181, b = 232, c=473,d=643 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =411, b = 322, c=643,d=742 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =542, b = 225, c=853,d=141 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =661, b = 242, c=293,d=241 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =771, b = 232, c=143,d=243 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =481, b = 212, c=353,d=444 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =681, b = 214, c=233,d=514 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =613, b = 241, c=123,d=355 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =271, b = 451, c=363,d=444 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =171, b = 232, c=463,d=743 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =419, b = 362, c=653,d=782 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =142, b = 227, c=853,d=149 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =661, b = 282, c=943,d=241 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =721, b = 282, c=444,d=343 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =482, b = 292, c=323,d=424 });
    lst .Add(new cPoint(){a =641, b = 219, c=123,d=514 });

}
```

}

I want to create 2 lists from original list applying a formula (written here for a vector):

one list will need to apply following formula to each column in original list

```
for (i = 1; i < N - 1; ++i)
{
    output[i] = (input[i - 1] + input[i] + input[i + 1]) / 3;
}
```

second list  will need to apply following formula to each column in original list

```
for (i = 1; i < N ; ++i)
{
    output[i] = input[i] - input[i - 1];
}
```

The issue here is I do not know how to get previous element and next element in a list, and also how to start doing it from second element in list and finish before the last element...

How to  apply each formula to each column in original list?

Comment: Are those `i`s are supposed to iterate over cPoint's fields? I'm afraid I don't understand what exactly is a problem here. Do you need a simple `for` loop?

Comment: yes, `i`s would be each element of a column in original list, I would like to do that for every column of original list, so the issue is how to iterate original list form second element to last-1 element?

Comment: You could convert the list into 2 dimensional or jagged array and then iterate through columns freely if that is the problem.

Comment: @cMinor Then how about making cPoint a one-dimensional array instead of a class? In such case iterating over its values would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `indexer` for your `cPoint` class:

```
class cPoint {
    static cPoint(){
      //We just care about the Fields of type double
      fields = typeof(cPoint).GetFields().Where(f=>f.FieldType==typeof(double)).ToArray();
      ColumnCount = fields.Length;
    }
    static FieldInfo[] fields;
    public static int ColumnCount {get;private set;}
    public double a;
    public double b;
    public double c;
    public double d;
    public double this[int index]{
       get {
          return (double)fields[index].GetValue(this);
       }
       set {
          fields[index].SetValue(this, value);
       }
    }
}

var list1 = lst.Select(x=> {                    
                cPoint output = new cPoint();
                output[0] = x[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < x.ColumnCount-1; i++){
                   output[i] = (x[i - 1] + x[i] + x[i + 1]) / 3;
                }
                return output;
            }).ToList();
var list2 = lst.Select(x=> {
                cPoint output = new cPoint();
                output[0] = x[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < x.ColumnCount; i++){
                   output[i] = x[i] - x[i - 1];
                }
                return output;
            }).ToList();
```

**NOTE**: You should define some `internal list` to expose your `Columns` in order, because using `Reflection` this way may have some loss in performance. However the **benefit** of using `Reflection` here is that you can add more or remove fields easily, just **define the fields in the order you want**, the order you define the fields is **exactly the order of your columns you want to loop through in a for loop**.

Comment: `props` could be initialised in static constructor. Then it's just once.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative aproach to placing an indexer on `cPoint`

```
    class cPoint
    {
        private readonly double[] values = new double[4];

        public double this[int index] {
            get { return values[index]; }
            set { values[index] = value; }
        }

        public int Length
        {
            get { return values.Length; }
        }

        public double a
        {
            get { return this[0]; }
            set { this[0] = value; }
        }
        public double b
        {
            get { return this[1]; }
            set { this[1] = value; }
        }
        public double c
        {
            get { return this[2]; }
            set { this[2] = value; }
        }
        public double d
        {
            get { return this[3]; }
            set { this[3] = value; }
        }
    };
```